# split the total time duration into rows

Tags: mysql

in parent table logintime is `10:00` and logouttime is `14:00` and in child talbe has eachjob's start time and end time. if an employee done 50 jobs. I want to split the total duration and display hourly jobs as rows?

```
Session #     jobs
10:00-11:00   12 
11:00-12:00   11 
12:00-13:00   11
13:00-14:00   16
```

Comment: exactly how would you decide that the employee was so productive after 1pm that they could do 16 jobs? An even split of 50 jobs over 4 hours would be 12.5 jobs/hr.

Answer (score 0):

Use this appropriately :
Also research before you ask it here .

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, endDate, startDate) AS hours_different
```